# Quitar el simbolo € de NumberFormat JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy formateando la moneda, pero quisiera que no me imprimiese el simbolo `€`.

```
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
})
```

Es posible quitarlo??

Estoy probando así:

```
let ofertaFormateado = formatterEuro.format(data.oferta);
var ofertaFormat = ofertaFormateado.replace(/[€]/g,'');
```

Me quita el simbolo € pero deja el espacio en blanco que hay entre el importe y el simbolo, al sacar el valor `console.log` me devuelve esto `1,50&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma que funciona pero quizá un poco enrevesada sería:

```js
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
});

const amount = formatterEuro.formatToParts(232).filter((p) => p.type !== 'currency').map((p) => p.value).join('').trim();

console.log(amount);
```

EDITADO:

La solución que estás utilizando sólo funcionaría con € y la lista de posibles monedas puede ser grande. La solución que te propongo funcionaría con cualquier moneda.

Si aun así prefieres hacerlo como dices simplemente bastaría con que añadas un espacio a la expresión regular del replace (fíjate que he añadido un espacio):

```
var ofertaFormat = ofertaFormateado.replace(/ [€]/g,'');
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, puede volver a mirar mi pregunta, haber que te parece?? @sergiomse

Comment: @Miguel He editado contestando a tu pregunta

Comment: He probado lo del espacio pero deja de funciona que quite el €, en tu función, donde esta el `232` es donde tengo que meter `ofertaFormateado` ?? @sergiomse

Comment: El 232 era un ejemplo. En tu caso sería `data.oferta`

Comment: entonces hay que quitar lo del formateo de moneda, no?

Comment: Ok ok! ahora entendi bien, funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias @sergiomse

Answer (score 1):

Si solo necesitas el número formateado en el idioma sin agregar el símbolo de la moneda, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

```js
const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'decimal',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});

console.log(formatterEuro.format(232));
console.log(formatterEuro.format(1.5));
console.log(formatterEuro.format(1.126));
```

Answer (score 0):

solamente necitas usar el siguiente código después de tu variable

```
.replace('€' , '')
```

quedaria así

```
let laVariableConNumero = 654554

        const formatterEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('en.US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD'
    }).format(laVariableConNumero).replace('$' , '');

console.log(formatterEuro )
```